# conda install python=3.8 takes hours

Tags: python, conda

Basically as in the title of this question. I wanted to upgrade python in my environment and I executed:

```
conda install python=3.8
```

after which an output starting with:

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
```

appeared with progress bars that I am not pasting here. In fact it does not take minutes, but the whole day already and claims to have done 11%... Not very optimistic. Is that normal? Why is that so? I can't imagine how any dependency solver (which should only be traversing a graph) can work that long.

I use conda 4.7.12.

Comment: Try this `conda create -n py38 python=3.8`  Note: it creates new env

Comment: @Sociopath, yes, creating a new env is of course an option. But I have a couple of them and would prefer to be able to upgrade python, instead of creating a new one and then reinstalling all the packages on top of the new python

Comment: @Maciek but changing Python versions entails installing different builds for almost every package anyway, excepting native libraries and `noarch` builds. Hence, mutating an existing env doesn't really save any time/space/downloading. Creating a new env is the more efficacious approach, and is sort of the idiom for Conda. If you need a starting point, dump the existing env first (`conda env export --no-builds > env.yaml`), edit or remove the versions you care about, then create the new env (`conda env create -n my_env -f env.yaml`).

Comment: In addition to what @merv said, creating new environments and installing all the necessary packages up front reduces the risk that the env will break.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. `conda` worked for one day or so and printed an extremely long output, which I, honestly, don't understand and don't even want to read.
Therefore, it seems that your are right, it'd be easier to create a new environment. Thank you again.